# How to control focus in child views in viewpager

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I am going to have some windows phone like GUI on Android.

I use ViewPager to implement the page switching effect.
It works well except the focus changing.

As image below, when I pressed right key when focus on A1/B2 in page 1, the current page should switch to page 2 and focus should on A2.

**All size and place of rects are placed by user, it means that I can not hard code them.**

The ViewPager handles page switching very well, but the focus always on the top right when a new page enter.

So, the question is is there any easy way to handle the focus? 
Or I have to calculate the focus myself by pre-focus coordinates?
Thanks!

[image]

BTW:
The same, when I pressed right key, the focus should change as below:

```
C1 --> B2
D1 --> C2
```

while when I pressed left key, the focus should change as below:

```
A2 --> A1/B2 (both are OK)
B2 --> C1
C2 --> D1
D2 --> D1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer at last and shared it here.

FocusFinder.getInstance().findNextFocusFromRect supports negative parameters, so what we need to do is call it with rect(A1) - (width,0) and rect(A2).

Comment: Can you expand on this answer?  Where are you putting the `FocusFinder` call?